# I am unable to fetch data with SWR in Nextjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, axios, swr

I am trying to use SWR in Next.js for the first time. I am using Axios to make http calls. The Axios make calls to protected API routes and I handled that using interceptor.
Here is one of the places where I used the SWR but I am getting `undefined` when I `console.log(data)` from `SWR`;

```
 const getProfile = async()=>{
    try {
       
        const res = await axiosPrivate.get<axiosGetCompanyProfile>(`/getcompany`, {withCredentials: true, headers: {Authorization: `${state?.in_memory}`}});
        console.log(res.data, 'mmmmnn')

        return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
        return error
    }
    
}


const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(`${getcompany`, getProfile)
```

What Am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error:

```
const getProfile = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axiosPrivate.get<axiosGetCompanyProfile>(`/getcompany`, {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: { Authorization: `${state?.in_memory}` },
        });
        return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};

const { data, error, isValidating } = useSWR('/getcompany', getProfile);
```

**useSWR's** first argument should be a string that serves as a key to identify the data (typically it's the API endpoint). The second argument is the fetcher function, which is getProfile in this case.

Comment: It is still showing undefined. Where is the syntax error?

Comment: Literally type you had it as the following ```${getcompany``` but it should be ```${getcompany}```

Comment: The axios response worked when I checked it inside the getProfile function. I can see the data that I fetched. However, SWR is not working, showing undefined and error is false.

Comment: hmm - try this ```if (isValidating) { return <div>Loading...</div>; } if (error) { return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>; }``` Make sure your *getProfile* function returns a JSON object. If not, this could be the issue. If the problem continues, share more code or details for better help.